# Type the value into input when clicked on with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list and it returns the transaction ID's. Currently this list is not useful since you need to copy the transaction ID and paste it into the input.[image: Transactions]

How this list is rendered:

```js
                  {this.state.all_transactions.map(tx => (
                    <li key={tx.key}>{tx}</li>
                  ))}
```

```js
    componentDidMount() {
      if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("wallet")) {
        (async () => {
          const arweave = Arweave.init();
          var address = window.sessionStorage.getItem("WalletAddress");
          const txids = await arweave.arql({
            op: "and",
            expr1: {
              op: "equals",
              expr1: "from",
              expr2: address
            },
            expr2: {
              op: "equals",
              expr1: "App-Name",
              expr2: "arshard"
            }
          });
          console.log(txids);
          this.setState({ all_transactions: txids });
        })();
      }
    }
```

For example, when I clicked on the one transaction it should take it's place on the "Enter TX" input below. So users won't have to be copy and paste.

I tried adding `onClick` before the list item however it didn't work.

More code:

```js
    state = {
      all_transactions: [],
      value: ''
    };
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({value: e.target.value});
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("transactionID", e.target.value);
    }
```

Comment: what about adding an event handler on each item of the list, then programmatically copy its content to the text field?

Comment: Or better yet, initiate the function for recover directly on click of any of the list items, passing the text value directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
   {this.state.all_transactions.map(tx => (
     <li key={tx.key} onClick={() => this.setState({ value: tx })}>{tx}</li>
   ))}
```

Just guessing here what you want to set it too since you didn't share the whole code. You basically need to use the same state what you use for your text input.